# angularjs show details view

Tags: json, angularjs

Hello guys i have a table of clients created from a json file and in each row there is a link to show the detail of each client!! it doesn't work i don't know why !! i really need some help !

here is the function in my factory

```
getUser : function(id){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('json/client.json')
        .success(function(data, status){
            factory.clients = data;

            deferred.resolve(factory.clients[id]);
        })
        .error(function(data, status){
            deferred.reject('Impossible de récupérer les clients!!');
        });
       return deferred.promise;
    }
```

here is my controller

```
app.controller('detailsCtrl', function($scope, patients,$routeParams){

var post = patients.getUser($routeParams.id).then(function(client){
$scope.name = post.name;


},function(msg){

alert(msg);
})

});
```

here is my routing

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){

$routeProvider
    .when('/',{templateUrl : 'table.html', controller: 'ClientCtrl'})
    .when('/details/:id',{templateUrl : 'details.html', controller: 'detailsCtrl'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});

 });
```

i really need some help thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

here is my controller

```
app.controller('detailsCtrl', function($scope, patients,$routeParams){

var post = patients.getUser($routeParams.id).then(function(client){
//if you need name only not post.name
$scope.name = client.name;
// if you need copy all object from json to $scope
angular.copy(client, $scope.lient)



},function(msg){

alert(msg);
})
```

});